# option strict on disallows implicit conversions between 'boolean?' to boolean in SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC4 (VB) Application.

I am trying to count the number of records that meet a specific condition:

```
Dim bridgeSelectedCount As Integer = db.IdeaGenerationDatas.Where(Function(s) s.PdId = ProjDivId And s.Selected = True).Count()
```

With the "option strict on" setting the compiler complains about this part of the code:

```
s.PdId = ProjDivId And s.Selected = True
```

I cannot put a

```
convert.toboolean
```

around that part because the SQL evaluation chokes on it at runtime.

The

```
s.Selected
```

CAN evaluate to NULL so I suspect that that is the error callout.  How can I get around this? (Without having to change the column definition in the DB Table that is)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing = True ?

Comment: Either or both of `ProjDivId` and `s.Selected` appear to be of type `Nullable(Of Boolean)` (a.k.a. `Boolean?`). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes. 
    s.Selected 

is a bit field of type Nullable.

Comment: Removing the "= True" does not help.

Comment: It was easier to just make the fields in question to NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the DB fields in question NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to `nullable` type, this might help.

```
Function(s) ((s.PdId.HasValue AndAlso s.PdId.value = ProjDivId) And 
(s.selected.HasValue AndAlso s.selected.value = True))
```

Comment: Adding the ".HasValue" does not help.

Comment: The compiler error reads:

    "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'"